# my Raspbverry Pi is continously interfacing with the SD Card

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, mysql, arm, nextcloud

My Raspberry Pi has a 128GB SD Card with Arch ARM and

- Apache
- NextCloud

installed on it and it seemingly non-stop interfaces with the SD Card. With `iotop` I found out that `mysqld` is seemingly the process that writes most data to the disk. In the mysql shell I then found the following:

```
show processlist;
+------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+
| Id   | User         | Host      | db        | Command | Time | State                    | Info             | Progress |
+------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+
|    1 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge coordinator | NULL             |    0.000 |
|    2 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|    3 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|    4 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL             |    0.000 |
|    5 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB shutdown handler  | NULL             |    0.000 |
| 1846 | root         | localhost | NULL      | Query   |    0 | Init                     | show processlist |    0.000 |
| 1852 | oc_stdcerr13 | localhost | nextcloud | Sleep   |    0 |                          | NULL             |    0.000 |
| 1853 | oc_stdcerr13 | localhost | nextcloud | Sleep   |    0 |                          | NULL             |    0.000 |
+------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

How can I give my SD Card a break? `/var/log` and `/tmp` are already on ramdisk (`tmpfs`)

Then when I continously executed the `show processlist` command, I also saw the following:

```
show processlist;
+------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id   | User         | Host      | db        | Command | Time | State                    | Info                                                                                                 | Progress |
+------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|    1 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge coordinator | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|    2 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|    3 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|    4 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|    5 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB shutdown handler  | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 2061 | oc_stdcerr13 | localhost | nextcloud | Query   |    0 | Init                     | SELECT `filecache`.`fileid`, `storage`, `path`, `path_hash`, `filecache`.`parent`, `name`, `mimetype |    0.000 |
| 2062 | root         | localhost | NULL      | Query   |    0 | Init                     | show processlist                                                                                     |    0.000 |
| 2063 | oc_stdcerr13 | localhost | nextcloud | Sleep   |    0 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
+------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show processlist;
+------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id   | User         | Host      | db        | Command | Time | State                    | Info                                                                                                 | Progress |
+------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|    1 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge coordinator | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|    2 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|    3 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|    4 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|    5 | system user  |           | NULL      | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB shutdown handler  | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 2061 | oc_stdcerr13 | localhost | nextcloud | Query   |    0 | Init                     | UPDATE `oc_filecache` SET `size` = '-1' WHERE (`fileid` = 15955) AND ((`size` <> '-1') OR (`size` IS |    0.000 |
| 2062 | root         | localhost | NULL      | Query   |    0 | Init                     | show processlist                                                                                     |    0.000 |
| 2063 | oc_stdcerr13 | localhost | nextcloud | Sleep   |    0 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
+------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```